# Using a For-Else executes both the conditions. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, for-else

I need to write a code, using loops, to find out if there is any common element in two lists. So, I wrote the following:

```
l1 = eval(input("Enter a list: "))
l2 = eval(input("Enter another list: "))
for i in range (len(l1)):
        for j in range (len(l2)):
                if l1[i] == l2[j]:
                        print("Overlapped")
                        break
else:
        print("Separated")
```

However, what I get as output is this:

```
Enter a list: [1,34,543,5,23,"apple"]
Enter another list: [54,23,6,213,"banana"]
Overlapped
Separated
```

Since the lists do have a common member, it should only print "Overlapped", but it ends up printing "Separated", too.

How do I fix this?
I'm using python 3.7

Thank you so much!!

Comment: your else might belong to the wrong for

Comment: Do you want "Overlapped" to be printed once and for all other elements "separated"? Or just "Overlapped" once

Comment: @Bazingaa I want just "Overlapped" to be printed once

Comment: Ooops! wrote my post before I saw the 'break' in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of tuples `(i, j)` and use a single `for` loop  to traverse the list of tuples. So either the output is `"Overlapped"` and the loop is breaks out or the `else` clause is executed and the output is `"Separated"`:

```py
for i, j in [(i, j) for i in range(len(l1)) for j in range(len(l2))]:
    if l1[i] == l2[j]:
        print("Overlapped")
        break
else:
    print("Separated")
```

Output:

> ```
> Enter a list: [1,34,543,5,23,"apple"]
> Enter another list: [54,23,6,213,"banana"]
> Overlapped
> ```

> ```
> Enter a list: [1,34,543,5,23,"apple"]
> Enter another list:  [54,234567,6,213,"banana"]
> Separated
> ```

---

Alternatively you can create a list of tuples with the indices of the equal list elements. Finally check if the list is empty:

```py
equal = [(i, j) for i in range (len(l1)) for j in range(len(l2)) if l1[i] == l2[j]]
if equal:
     print("Overlapped")
else:
     print("Separated")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll need to break out of *both* loops for the `else` to work as you expect, I think it'll be easier to just not use the `else` at all here. If you define your code in a function, you can use `return` to break out of both loops at the same time.

For example:

```
def have_common_elements():
    l1 = eval(input("Enter a list: "))
    l2 = eval(input("Enter another list: "))
    for i in range (len(l1)):
        for j in range (len(l2)):
            if l1[i] == l2[j]:
                return True
    return False # will only happen if the previous `return` was never reached, similar to `else`

have_common_elements()
```

Sample:

```
Enter a list: [1,34,543,5,23,"apple"]
Enter another list: [54,23,6,213,"banana"]
True

Enter a list: [1,34,543,5,25,"apple"]
Enter another list: [54,23,6,213,"banana"]
False
```

Comment: I think the OP wants for these two lists only "Overlapped" to be printed